# What is difference between column title vs column name

Tags: database, teradata

I studying Teradata DBMS, and Teradata can be has column title when create table

like this

```
CREATE SET TABLE HR.Employees (
   GlobalID INTEGER title 'Test title',
   FirstName VARCHAR(30),
   LastName VARCHAR(30),
   DateOfBirth DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD',
   JoinedDate DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD',
   DepartmentCode BYTEINT
)
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( GlobalID );
```

but comment now allowed. If I want add comment to column, I have to execute query below.

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN {DATABASENAME}.{TABLENAME}.{COLUMNNAME} AS '{255 characters of text}';
```

and this won't be seen when create table script in default settings.

What difference?

But other DBMS (MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle) doesn't have column title. They just have column name.

Comment: Other RDBMS **do** have comments on columns!

Comment: A title is like a permanent alias but just for the output of Selects, i.e. `SocSec# title 'Social Security Number`. This was useful when creating reports in BTEQ, you can code `select *` and it's showing the title in the result.

Comment: In Studio you can generate the DDL including comments using "Teradata -> Generate DDL" in the mouse menu.